# Sigaction declaration in functions

Tags: c, unix, sigaction

Is sigaction in Unix declared only once in `main` function, or should I declare it inside every function my `main` calls, so if a signal comes when the execution is not inside my `main`, the signal handler will invoke? So, do I have to declare `sigaction` only once at the start of `main()` or do I have to declare it in every function?

Comment: By "declare" do you really mean *call*? Then you should call it only once for each signal. The state of a signal is usually per-process, and for some signals per-thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call `sigaction()` in every function.  It sets a (global) signal handler for a given signal which remains the signal handler until you change it — by another call to `sigaction()` for the same signal.  You can call `sigaction()` in `main()`, but that is not obligatory either.  You can call it in selected other functions.

Note that you need to call `sigaction()` once for each different signal that you want to handle — or ignore.  It is often beneficial to call a function which loops over a list of signals, setting the appropriate handler(s) for each signal.  Thank goodness you don't have to do that in each function you call!

In general, avoid mixing calls to `signal()` and `sigaction()` in the same program.  If you're using `sigaction()` anywhere, use it everywhere.  However, if you insist on being perverse, then you can use "`sigaction()` or `signal()`" in the first paragraph where I only mentioned `sigaction()`.

Note that you can use `sigaction()` to find out how a signal is handled without setting new signal handling.  With `signal()` you can find out (more or less) how the signal was being handled, but you have to set an action as well.  Just another reason to prefer `sigaction()` over `signal()`.

<sup>*Note that I'm assuming that 'declare' in the question means 'call' in some shape or form.  You don't declare `sigaction()` in any function; you include `<signal.h>` to declare it.*</sup>